# Magento 2.1.9 - Cannot seem to overwrite JS comonent template in custom module

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

Having trouble trying to overwrite a JS component template at checkout. Here is my module structure and code for this specific task:

*app/code/MY/MODULE/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="iosc-place-order-button" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Onestepcheckout_Iosc/js/view/placeorder</item>
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">summary</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">900</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">MY_MODULE/view/place_order</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

*app/code/MY/MODULE/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Onestepcheckout/Iosc/template/view/place_order.html': 'MY/MODULE/template/view/place_order.html'
        }
    }
};
```

*app/code/MY/MODULE/view/frontend/web/template/view/place_order.html*

```
<h1>HELLO!!</h1>
```

I've echoed the contents of `$this->_request->getFullActionName()` and it returns `checkout_index_index`

Is there anything that looks out of place here, I cannot see why it's not working! Any help would be greatly appreicated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll kick yourself for this one. Needs to be Onestepcheckout_Iosc and MY_MODULE in requirejs-config.js.

app/code/MY/MODULE/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Onestepcheckout_Iosc/template/view/place_order.html': 'MY_MODULE/template/view/place_order.html'
        }
    }
};
```

I'm unable to verify as I do not have Onestepcheckout Iosc but that's the correct way of overriding a web template.

Update: I adapted your code slightly to work with Amasty OneStepCheckout and it's printing HELLO!! on the checkout so the rest of the code must be ok.

Comment: Ouch! I hate those moments, but you are a saviour!